# Why is the conclusion correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is my problem :

Let $ n $ be a non zero natural integer. Show that any number strictly greater than $ \frac{n^4}{16} $ can be written, in at most one way, as the product of two of its divisors having a difference $ \le n $.

Here is a way to answer (without the conclusion –– proof by contradiction)

If we suppose that there are two ways of writing, then we can find $ a \gt c \ge d \gt d $ such that $ a-b \le n $ and $ ab=cd \gt n^4/16 $.

We note that $ (a+b)^2 - (a-b)^2 = 4ab $

We also note that $ (c+d)^2 - (c-d)^2 = 4cd $

We then set $ p = a+b $,  $ q = a-b $, $ r = c+d $ and $ s = c-d $.

So $ p^2-q^2 = 4ab = 4cd = r^2-s^2 \gt \frac{n^2}{4} $

On the other hand, $ a-b \le n \Rightarrow (a-b)^2 \le n^2 \iff q^2 \le n^2 $

So $ p^2-q^2 = r^2-s^2 \iff p^2-r^2 = q^2-s^2 \le q^2 \le n^2$

My book concludes by saying this:

As we have $ r^2 \gt \frac{n^4}{4}$ (i.e. $ r \gt \frac{n^2}{2}$ ) and $ p \gt r $, hence we have $ p^2-r^2 \gt (\frac{n^2}{2} + 1)^2 - (\frac{n^2}{2})^2 \ge n^2 +1 $

Which is a contradiction with the fact that $ p^2-r^2 \le n^2 $

There is a similar question in this link, but it doesn't help me [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667451/why-is-p-necessarily-greater-than-r-in-this-number-theory-problem)

I disagree with (or do not understand) the last strict inequality. Because
$ -r^2 \lt -(\frac{n^2}{2})^2 $ is correct, but not $ -r^2 \gt -(\frac{n^2}{2})^2 $.

Comment: You have $n^4/16$ in your (duplicated) first paragraph instead of $n^2/16$.